# TFS 2008 to 2010 migration Missing Links from Work Items to Changesets

Tags: tfs, tfs-2008

I have used TFS migration tool to migrate source code along with version history from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010.  Then I used sfts(scrum for team system v3) migration utility to migrate workitems from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010. It also migrated everything for me.  But now I have missing link between workitem and changeset.  How can I migrate that?  Is sfts migration utility not doing that? any help or advice on that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK migration tool was needed during 2005->2008 migration. For 2008->2010 migration you don't need any migration tools. It can be done on DB level. I know we did it this way and I know it is possible. Move your TFS 2008 database to TFS 2010 DB. The same DB, the same links inside workitems as before...